# How can I display an image its bytes come byte by byte through the serial port in WinFormApp?//

Tags: c#, image, serial-port, jpeg

This is the code that I've tried to write. I first tell the "LinkSprite JPEG Camera" to take a picture and then I read the JPEG file contents.

There are no errors and the code is working, but the problem is the result comes was very slowly, I've seen "done" *i.e. reached to FFD9* after more than 2 minutes. The message of the message box emerged after that much time.

I want get the image which is stored in the camera buffer after sending the "take picture" command and to display it in the form.

My code is:

```
// public static byte[] ReceivedMsg = new byte[256];
// public static int factor = 0x0000;
// public static UInt16 M = 0;
// public static byte MH = (byte)((M >> 8) & 0xff);
// public static byte ML = (byte)((M >> 0) & 0xff);

private void TakeSnap_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // First set the size of the image //
    byte[] sendCmd = new byte[9] { 0x56, 0x00, 0x31, 0x05, 0x04, 0x01, 0x00, 0x19, 0x11 };

    try
    {
        if (!(CamPort.IsOpen)) CamPort.Open(); // If the port is closed!,Open it again //
        CamPort.Write(sendCmd, 0, 9);
        Thread.Sleep(100);// Wait for the camera //
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            ReceivedMsg[i] = (byte)(CamPort.ReadByte()); // Store the returned msg //
        }
        if (ReceivedMsg[0].ToString("x") == "76" && ReceivedMsg[1].ToString("x") ==    "0" && ReceivedMsg[2].ToString("x") == "31" && ReceivedMsg[3].ToString("x") == "0" && ReceivedMsg[4].ToString("x") == "0")
        {
            try
            {
                CamPort.DiscardOutBuffer();
                CamPort.DiscardInBuffer();
                byte[] TakePicCmd = new byte[] { 0x56, 0x00, 0x36, 0x01, 0x00 };
                CamPort.Write(TakePicCmd, 0, 5);
                Thread.Sleep(100);// Wait for the camera //
                for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
                {
                    ReceivedMsg[i] = (byte)(CamPort.ReadByte());
                }
                if (ReceivedMsg[0].ToString("x") == "76" && ReceivedMsg[1].ToString("x") == "0" && ReceivedMsg[2].ToString("x") == "36" && ReceivedMsg[3].ToString("x") == "0" && ReceivedMsg[4].ToString("x") == "0")
                { 
                    try
                    {
                        CamPort.DiscardOutBuffer();
                        CamPort.DiscardInBuffer();
                        byte[] ReadSizeCommand = new byte[5] { 0x56, 0x00, 0x34, 0x01, 0x00 };
                        CamPort.Write(ReadSizeCommand, 0, 5);
                        Thread.Sleep(100);// Wait for the camera //
                        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
                        {
                            ReceivedMsg[i] = (byte)(CamPort.ReadByte());
                        }
                        if (ReceivedMsg[0].ToString("x") == "76" && ReceivedMsg[1].ToString("x") == "0" && ReceivedMsg[2].ToString("x") == "34" && ReceivedMsg[3].ToString("x") == "0" && ReceivedMsg[4].ToString("x") == "4" && ReceivedMsg[5].ToString("x") == "0" && ReceivedMsg[6].ToString("x") == "0")
                        {   
                            int ImageSize=(((ReceivedMsg[7] & 0x00ff) << 8) | (ReceivedMsg[8] & 0x00ff));
                            try
                            {
                                CamPort.DiscardOutBuffer();
                                CamPort.DiscardInBuffer();
                                byte[] body = new byte[32];
                                byte[] header = new byte[5];
                                bool EndFlag = false;    
                                while (!EndFlag)
                                {
                                    ReadJpegFileCommand();
                                    Thread.Sleep(25);// Wait for the camera //
                                    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) header[i] = (byte)CamPort.ReadByte();
                                    ////// If the first 5 bytes matching [76 00 32 00 00] then read the body and display the image //////
                                    if (((int)header[0] == 0x76) && (header[1] == 0x00) && (header[2] == 0x32) && (header[3] == 0x00) && (header[4] == 0x00))
                                    {
                                        for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++)
                                            body[i] = (byte)CamPort.ReadByte();

                                        for (int i = 1; i < body.Length; i++)// check if reached to the last two bytes(FF D9) of the body //
                                        {
                                            if ((body[i - 1] == 0xFF) && (body[i - 0] == 0xD9))
                                            {
                                                EndFlag = true;
                                                MessageBox.Show("done");
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        MessageBox.Show("Unexpted Returned value "); // the first 5 bytes does not match the header 
                                    }
                                }
                            }

                            catch (System.Exception ex) { MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); }

                        }
                        else { MessageBox.Show("Reset the camera and start again0 !!"); }
                    }
                    catch (System.Exception ex) { MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); }
                }
                else { MessageBox.Show("Reset the camera and start again1 !!"); }
              }
            catch (System.Exception ex) { MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); }
        }
        else { MessageBox.Show("Reset the camera and try again2 !!"); }
    }
    catch (System.Exception ex) { MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); }
}

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------//

public void ReadJpegFileCommand()
{
    try
    {
        MH = (byte)(factor / 0x100);
        ML = (byte)(factor % 0x100);
        byte[] ReadImageCommand = new byte[16] { 0x56, 0x00, 0x32, 0x0C, 0x00, 0x0A, 0x00, 0x00, MH, ML, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x20, 0x00, 0x0a };
        CamPort.Write(ReadImageCommand, 0, 16);
        factor += 0x20;
    }

    catch (System.Exception ex) { MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); }
}
```

**The camera is: LinkSprite JPEG Camera**

[The Camera Manual](http://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Sensors/Imaging/1274419957.pdf)

[Mbed Example (Test program)](http://mbed.org/cookbook/Camera_LS_Y201)

**How can I reach FFD9 "Quickly"** and then **how can I display** the bytes that are stored in the data array as an image in the `picturebox1` that I've added to the form?

`CamPort` is the name of the serial port control.

Comment: You should definitely refactor your code a bit, it's really hard to read it. And almost impossible to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What baud rate is your serial port running at? Serial ports are not very fast at transmitting data, even at their highest speeds which is 115200 baud in your case. Even then, serial comms like this can be prone to drop random characters if the baud rate is set to high, or is mismatched on both ends.

As far as getting it to display in a picture box, you will need to convert the byte array into an Image class object of some type. This isn't difficult if your input array is correct and not missing any characters. There are a plethora of tutorials on how to do this.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharplanguage/thread/a20fcf5f-9d32-4d32-85d0-c8dd4d978e15

http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?496495-Manually-created-byte-array-to-picture-box.

Comment: 38400 >> How can I overcome this problem I don't know why did this happen .. both sender and receiver has the same baud rate ...!
when I SEND reset command I get the response quickly :(

Comment: You could try bumping up your baud rate to see if you can transmit any quicker, but thats about the extent I can think of as far as speed goes. Also, I assume that you get your RESET response so quickly because it is only 4 bytes (76 00 26 00), and your images are much larger than this(in the kilobyte range). If you wait, do the images successfully trasnsmit, but at a very slow speed? If this is the case, bump your baud rate up and see what happens.